# Streaming vs downloading media data usage?

Tags: file, io, download, filesystems, video-streaming

Let's say there is `test.mp4 (mp4 480 resolution)` which is `40 Mb` in size.
Is there a difference in streaming and downloading data usage? Theoritically both consumes 40 Mb data in general as both will fetch the file from the location of server. Streaming might process the file faster but would it consume the same data i.e 40mb?

Answer (score 2):

If you upload your video **test.mp4** of size 40 MB in youtube. It will compress that video using its own parameter and if any user download or stream that video in same quality **(eg 360 , 480 , 720p or others)** without skipping any part of it  then the data usage will be same...

If you have 40 ltrs of water in you tank(i.e 40 MB video) weather you empty your tank by taking bath/shower (i.e streaming) or you finish it by pouring in bathtub (i.e download)...The usage will be 40 ltrs...

Downloading is the better option for using less bandwidth. Unless you're saving to disk and/or holding static prebuffering in ram while streaming, any reverse jumps in your watching are going to completely rebuffer from where you jumped backwards to. Every rebuffer will take up additional bandwidth that you didn't wish to use, and will ultimately add up to more bandwidth used for watching by stream than by downloading and watching after :)